# Silverlight setting ZIndex of UserControl

Tags: c#, silverlight

How do I set the ZIndex of a UserControl?
I have tried

```
Canvas.SetZIndex((Tile)sender, 99);
((Tile)sender).SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, 99);
```

Tile is the name of my UserControl
I have a Rectangle inside the UserControl that is what actually appears on the screen.
I have also tried

```
Canvas.SetZIndex(((Tile)sender).rect, 99);
((Tile)sender).rect.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, 99);
```

Edit:

Here is what the XAML for my UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="Carcassonne.Tile"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="76" d:DesignWidth="76">

    <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Rectangle x:Name="rect" 
                   Width="76" Height="76"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush x:Name="tileImage">
                    <ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <RotateTransform x:Name="rotation" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" Angle="0" />
                    </ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
                </ImageBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Is you user control located inside a Canvas panel? Relative to what are you trying to set zIndex? In other words, could you provide the XAML code of your markup?

Comment: @Pavlo Glazkov Yes the User Control is inside a Canvas panel. I have many user controls and I need to set their Z-Index relative to the main canvas or to each other. Please see my the edit in my opening post.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some assumptions:

- You have some outer UserControl or Page.
- This outer UserControl contains a Canvas.
- This Canvas in turn has several direct children which are instances of your `Carcassonne.Tile` control.
- You have attached an event handler to each tiles Left Mouse Down event in which you would like to bring the tile affected to the top.

The being the case the code you have already used should work:=

```
Canvas.SetZIndex((Tile)sender, 99);
```

Except as you click on other tiles they too end up with a 99 Z-Index.  What you need is to hold in common the last Zindex value used and then increment and use its value each time the event happens.

This answer probably doesn't help because of all the assumptions one or more of which may be wrong.  If you could be more descriptive in your question a better matching answer could be found.

Comment: All your assumptions are correct. When the mouse button is pressed down, I set the ZIndex of the active tile to 99. When the mouse button is released, I set the ZIndex to 98. The 'active' tile should always be on top. This is the effect I am going after, but the code that I have posted does not do the trick.

Comment: @Arizona1911:  According to all the information you have provided so far it should.  Hence there is still information you have that we don't.  Only you would know what that might be.